# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function deleteUser()
{
    var arr = new Array();
    $("input:checkbox[name=ids]:checked").each(function(){
        arr.push($(this).val());
    });

    var arr =  $.parseJSON(arr);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url('/AdminCP/Users/delete'); ?>",
        data: {'users': arr},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            $("body").append(data);
        }
    });
}
```

I have this project that i been working on its still in development. 
i'm Getting " Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input " Error when the function runs.

Any ideas ?

Comment: It does not make sense to call `$.parseJSON()` with a JavaScript object. That function is for parsing JSON notation in a string.

Comment: var `arr` is already defined. No point redefining it. Also, use [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to convert an array to a JSON string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are meaning:

```
 var arr =  JSON.stringify(arr); // converts your array to json
```

`$.parseJSON` parse the JSON and gives you the js object.

Comment: downvoter, I made a typo It should have been stringify

Comment: fix noticed. Your new theory looks plausible.

Comment: Well, he *might* want to do that, but that will result in the array of users being passed as a single JSON string parameter. Without involving JSON at all, however, and just passing the array directly, jQuery will create separate HTTP parameters for each array element. Which way is correct depends on the server-side code of course.

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify somewhat:

```
function deleteUser()
{
    var postData = $("input:checkbox[name=ids]:checked").serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url('/AdminCP/Users/delete'); ?>",
        data: postData,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            $("body").append(data);
        }
    });
}
```